# How can i get tables from my database in php to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, echo

I've set the values in two tables in php whle I connected it with my database  but I wanted to get this table to my javascript

```
$tab=array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
$tab1=array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)){
    $tab[$row['mois']-1]=$row['Num_ticketORSLA'];
    $tab1[$row['mois']-1]=$row['Num_ticketSLA'];        
}
```

I tried to get the values from this table to another one in javascript, I used echo json_encode:

```
var getvalue1 = <?php echo json_encode($tab1) ?>;
```

but it wont work.
Edit : 
here's my code

```
<?php
    // Connect to database server
        mysql_connect("localhost" , "root" , "")or die (mysql_error());

    // Select database
        mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());


    // SQL query
        $strSQL = "SELECT MONTH(ost_ticket.created) as mois ,
                (SELECT count(*) FROM ost_ticket WHERE  ost_ticket.sla_id = 0  AND MONTH(created)=mois AND (ost_ticket.status_id=2 OR ost_ticket.status_id=3) ) as Num_ticketORSLA ,
                (SELECT count(*) FROM ost_ticket WHERE  ost_ticket.sla_id = 1  AND MONTH(created)=mois AND (ost_ticket.status_id=2 OR ost_ticket.status_id=3) ) as Num_ticketSLA ,
                FROM ost_ticket
                WHERE ost_ticket.status_id = 3 OR ost_ticket.status_id = 2 
                GROUP BY mois 
                ORDER BY mois ASC ";

    // Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
        $rs = mysql_query($strSQL)or die ("could not find");

    // Loop the recordset $rs
    // Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array
            $tab=array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
            $tab1=array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)){
                    $tab[$row['mois']-1]=$row['Num_ticketORSLA'];
                    $tab1[$row['mois']-1]=$row['Num_ticketSLA'];        
                }


    // Close the database connection
    mysql_close();?>

<script>



var getvalue = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($tab) ?>")
var getvalue1 = <?php echo json_encode($tab1) ?>;


var barChartData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [getvalue[0],getvalue[1],getvalue[2],getvalue[3],getvalue[4],getvalue[5],getvalue[6]]


        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : [getvalue1[0],getvalue1[1],getvalue1[2],getvalue1[3],getvalue1[4],getvalue1[5],getvalue1[6]]

        }
    ]

}
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });
}


</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by **"it wont work"**, please clarify the error, expected and actual I/O

Comment: I get nothing in my webpage no message error... nothing just a blank page

Comment: Try the following: `var getvalue1 = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($tab1) ?>");`

Comment: You are mixing php code with Javascript wrongly. You have to quote the value returned by php in your javascript. `var getValue1 = '<?php echo json_encode($tab1); ?>';`

Comment: please post the code that manipulates `getvalue1`

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer this is not needed since the resultant array/object can be used directly at JS, enclosing the result in quotes requires another call to json parse

Comment: I wrote the code, and `var getvalue1 = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($tab1) ?>");` wont work too they only give me a blank page

Comment: is there an HTML element with this ID `"canvas"` ?

Comment: Yes `<div style="width: 50%">
   <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
  </div>`